# Twin unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have this structure:

```
  <ul>
      <li class="paginator"><a class="active">1</a></li>
      <li class="paginator"><a>2</a></li>
      <li class="paginator"><a>3</a></li>
  </ul>
  ... bunch of html code
  <ul>
      <li class="paginator"><a class="active">1</a></li>
      <li class="paginator"><a>2</a></li>
      <li class="paginator"><a>3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Which is an unordered anchor, every time the user clicks on an anchor it becomes of the *active* class. My question is: What's the best way to duplicate this effect on both anchors. So far, when i click on the anchor 2 of the bottom, it succesfully get the *active* class, but the anchor 2 of top doesn't. Is there a way to have something like twin or cloned elements?

Comment: Can we have fiddle please ?

Comment: I think you gotta show us a bit of your js/jquery.

Comment: You mean like this -> **https://jsfiddle.net/s7bekp23/**

Comment: I've seen great personalities always answer into comments! :D

Comment: @adeneo that is exactly what i was looking for: Could you please post your answer to upvote it?

Comment: @JulioBastida - sure !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index of the clicked `li.paginator` element, and set the active class to any other `li.paginator` with the same index using `nth-child`, that way the class gets added to both UL's

```js
var lis = $('.paginator').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
    var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();
    
 lis.find('a').removeClass('active');
    lis.filter(':nth-child('+(idx+1)+')').find('a').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
a {cursor : pointer}
a.active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li class="paginator"><a class="active">test 1</a></li>
      <li class="paginator"><a>test 2</a></li>
      <li class="paginator"><a>test 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- ... bunch of html code -->
  <ul>
      <li class="paginator"><a class="active">test 1</a></li>
      <li class="paginator"><a>test 2</a></li>
      <li class="paginator"><a>test 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up like this is should work the same for both ul elements, unless you are wanting the elements to mirror each other:

```
 $('.paginator').click(function(){ $(this).find('a').addClass("active") });
```

Comment: Exactly, i'm trying to mirror the effect